# ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE --- server goes off when logging on the website fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, passport.js

I want to do authentication on my website. I did it with passport.js, and everything seems to be good, but there is one big issue. If i type wrong username or password while logging in, the whole server goes down.I have got ' if ' statements in my code which should show flash massages when password is wrong. It works perfectly with registration. Below are parts of code in my files with login authentication and whole error from the console.

**error code**

https://prnt.sc/s70s5m

**file routes.js**

```
const User            = require("../models/user");
const Post            = require("../models/post");

module.exports = function(app,passport){

app.get("/login", function(req,res){
    res.render("login", {message:req.flash("loginMessage")});
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-login", {
    successRedirect:"/",
    failureRedorect:"/login",
    failureFlash:true
}))};
```

**file passport.js**

```
   passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {

    User.findOne({ 'local.username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        if (!user)
        {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
        {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 
        }
        else
             return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

**file user.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  bcrypt   = require("bcrypt-nodejs");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        username:String,
        password:String
    }
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typed wrong in `failureRedorect:"/login"`. Correct is: failureRedirect.

Comment: Oh my god, I analyzed the code few days and couldnt see it. Really thank you man.